# how to start with MS dynamics CRM from basics?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

Im new to Microsoft dynamics CRM, actually i moved from .NET to CRM, i dont know where to start.

Can anyone help to overcome this? In stackoverflow is there any chat room availalble regarding MS Dynamics CRM2011

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start from [Microsoft Dynamics CRM Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm/bb467596). They have [Dynamics CRM 2011 Developer Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23416) and of course you need [CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309408.aspx)

Comment: thanks paramosh... i had finished downloading 30 day trial version... but as a next step i dont know what basics want to undergo such as creating a sample application

Comment: Play with customizing entities, next dig into more complex things like creating plug ins, custom workflow activities. SDK contains sample

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the specialization you're aiming for, there are different ways. Given your background, I'm guessing you're going for developer competence.

In the addition to @paramosh I can suggest that you register a new organization on-line (free for 30 days) and achieve the following.

1. Make CRM say "Hello" when you open creation of a contact. (JavaScript)
2. Make CRM Switch the first and last names when saving it. (C#/plugin)

You can get started by preparing your VS by installing CRM Developer Toolkit and getting CRM SDK. Then, you'll have a project group under C# called CRM Dynamics. In there, you can select plugin project. Do what you'd like in the *Execute* method. After that, you compile and register the assembly as well as the steps using plugin registration tool to your CRM. Test it and voilà!

This is the answer to your question (you're welcome to check it as an answer). If you need more detailed help, I suggest that you make a new post, hence splitting the huge starting threshold into pieces.

Try to set up each questions according to this.

1. What do you want to achieve (small baby steps)?
2. What have you tried (if possible, present **some** code, not 1000 lines)?
3. What is happening that you feel is incorrect or unwanted?

The clearer questions you ask, the faster and better help people will be prone to offer you.

Comment: thanks Konrad Viltersten... i had finished downloading 30 day trial version... but as a next step i dont know what basics want  to undergo such as creating a sample application.